# Что значит символ ">" в Git?

Tags: git, linux

Недавно начал изучать работу в Git. После добавленного мною коммита вместо обычного символа "$" в начале строке повился другой символ ">". При этом Git не реагирует на какие-либо команды. Поиск в гугле особых результатов не дал, поэтому хочу спросить, что я сделал и как выйти из этого режима?
Вот код для наглядности:

> Макс@МАКС-ПК ~/Desktop/Craze_Bootstrap (master)
>
> $ git commit -m "Dobavil header'
>
> ">" git status

Answer (score 5, accepted):

У вас сообщение к коммиту не закончено, т.к. интерпретатор ожидает в конце кавычки того же типа, что и в начале.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Можно ли это исправить, не закрывая git?

Comment: Кавычку добавьте и нажмите Enter.

Comment: Спасибо большое. Помогло.

Comment: ctrl+c и правильно ввести команду git commit -m "Dobavil header"